# What is the equation for the curve in an Ids-Vds graph that separates linear and saturated regions in a MOSFET transistor?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos

[image: MOSFET Ids/Vds graph]

This curve separates Linear/Saturated regions in an Ids=f(Vds), with varying Vgs, graph for a 0.35um NMOS.
I understand that I can connect the points where:

```
Vds = Vgs - Vt
```

with lines, but I would prefer getting the curve function.

For reference, it's the faint blue logarithmic curve in the image:

Comment: Id Vgs forward current equation gives that curve if I am not wrong.

Comment: Use the MOSFET current equation in saturation and replace VGS-VTH by VDS.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is given by:

Vgs - Vth = sqrt(Id / (β * (W/L)))

where:

β is uCox